# the name "model" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have an asp.net mvc 5 application with a few views. All my views are working fine, but one of them keeps giving me an error at the top where I have `@model X.Models.MyModel`

"The name "model" does not exist in the current context"

I'm not sure why this is happening to only 1 view, what can I provide that can be of help to solving this issue?

web.config file or something of the sort?

Comment: Did you create this view as a strongly typed view? If not then you may encounter this error.

Comment: Check your `~/Views/Web.config`. What's in it?

Comment: I will check and post, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a new strongly typed view and it seems to be working now. Thanks to Greg and haim in the comments

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @KyleMit I did vote up, just wanted to mention them, and they were comments not answers, also my answer is not "thank you" I provided my fix before mentioning those that helped me

Comment: just for historical clarity, jrummell had posted his suggestion to use a strongly typed views four minutes prior to you posting this answer.  So this post didn't really contribute anything further, which is how and why it got flagged and put in the review queues.  Since you told jrummel his answer didn't address your question, he subsequently deleted his post.

Comment: no actually he never mentioned using a strongly typed view, he said I can access model fields using the keyword "Model" with the capital M, I'm not here to argue bro, but don't say things that aren't accurate